# ASP.NET (webforms) Devexpress AspxImageGallery (e.index)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, devexpress

My problem is that I need to take the text from the ImageGallery Item and add it as a row in aspxgridview but I can't do that because I am not able to load that text in javascript or in c#. All what I know is the e.index which represents the number of the image clicked. 
here is a part of my code :

```
    <Items>
        <dx:ImageGalleryItem Text="blablabla" ImageUrl="~/Models/24.jpg">
        </dx:ImageGalleryItem>


    </Items>
    <SettingsTableLayout RowsPerPage="1" />
    <ClientSideEvents FullscreenViewerShowing="OnFullscreenViewerShowing" />
</dx:ASPxImageGallery>
```

```
     var imageIndex = 0;
    function OnFullscreenViewerShowing(s, e) {
        imageIndex = e.index;
        if (e.index == 0) {

       alert(e.index.text);

        } else if (e.index == 1) {

        }
        popup.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set a `ClientInstanceName` on the `ASPxImageGallery` control. Setting the ClientInstanceName will enable client side events for the control.